# How to replace entries of a makefile variable

Tags: for-loop, sed, makefile, gnu-make

I have a variable `MY_VAR` inside a Makefile defined as `MY_VAR = read orange yellow blue green white black`. I am trying to write a Makefile function/macro that takes a list of colors as input and replaces them by appending a suffix to them. Inside the Makefile I can do this as
`MY_NEW_VAR = $(shell echo $(MY_VAR) | sed -e 's/black/blackcolor/' -e 's/red/redcolor/' -e 's/white/whitecolor/')` but running into problems when doing this using a function with `for` loop.

```
define append_color
for color in $(2); do \
  $(eval $(1) += $(shell echo $(MY_VAR) | sed 's/$$color/$$color$(3)/')); \
done;      
endef
```

Here `$2` is the list of colors to replace and `$(1)` will contain the result and `$3` contains the suffix to append.
Below is the function call inside Makefile:

```
MY_VAR = read orange yellow blue green white black
$(call append_color,MY_NEW_VAR,black red white,color)
```

The makefile returns the following error at the point of call to this function inside the Makefile:

```
Makefile.mk:50: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing or alternatives for doing the same ?

Thanks

Comment: you cannot use shell-like `for` loop in makefile outside of recipe. You should use `$(foreach ...)`, see GNU make docs https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html

Comment: Also, do you always need to add suffix to all color entries in the variable or only to certain colors? If it is always all entries then you could use `$(patsubst %, %color, $(MY_VAR))`.

Comment: No, the entries to which suffix needs to be added are provided in `$(3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways how you can accomplish your task:
Using the classical `patsubst` function:

```
append_color = $(patsubst %,%$(3),$(filter $(2),$(1))) $(filter-out $(2),$(1))
MY_NEW_VAR := $(call append_color,$(MY_VAR),black red white,color)
```

Or with `foreach`:

```
append_color = $(foreach w,$(1),$(if $(filter $(w),$(2)),$(w)$(3),$(w)))
MY_NEW_VAR := $(call append_color,$(MY_VAR),black red white,color)
```

Comment: Just a note that first approach will reorder the colors

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was wanting.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, using only make functions

```
define replace
$(foreach color,$2,\
    $(eval $1 := $(subst $(color),$(color)$3,$($1))))

endef

COLOR_LIST := red black green orange

COLOR_TO_REPLACE := black green

$(eval $(call replace,COLOR_LIST,$(COLOR_TO_REPLACE),suf))

$(info $(COLOR_LIST))
```

You append the suffix to the color one by one, at each expansion of `eval`.
(To break it down, the `replace` is first expanded to
`$(foreach color,black green,$(eval COLOR_LIST := $(subst $(color),$(color)suf,$(COLOR_LIST))))` then the `eval` part is expand in this order.

Note that `suf` in the call to the macro shall not have any spaces in it, or they will be added too.